# Closed-form solution to a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

Consider the following $n \times n$ matrix with a particularly nice structure:
\begin{equation}\mathbf{P}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& \dots&0 & 0 &1\\
0 & 0&  \dots&0 & \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\vdots& & & & & \vdots \\
0 &\frac{1}{n-1}& \dots&\frac{1}{n-1}&\frac{1}{n-1}&\frac{1}{n-1}\\
\frac{1}{n} &\frac{1}{n} &\dots&\frac{1}{n} &\frac{1}{n} &\frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix} ,
\end{equation}
and let
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\pi}=(1,2, \text{ ..., }n).
\end{equation}
Is there any hope in fiding closed-form expressions for the elements of the $n$-dimensional vector $\mathbb{w}$ (not in terms of matrix inverses) that solve the following set of linear equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{P}\\
\mathbf{\pi}
\end{pmatrix}\mathbb{w}=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{a}\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $a_i=\frac{1}{i+1}-C$ and $C=\frac{2(n+1-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j})}{n(n+1)}$, or is that a hopeless endeavor?

(See also: [Eigenvectors of a particular transition matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156090/eigenvectors-of-a-particular-transition-matrix))

Comment: Is $\pi$ a diagonal matrix with the said entries? Also $I-P$ is singular, so anyways we cannot write $(I-P)^{-1}$...

Comment: I guess $\pi$ is a vector, so it's a pseudo-inverse + a normalization condition on $w$. If I am correct, that system is called Poisson equation for a Markov chain.

Comment: But Federico then it's a syntax error, because how does $\pi$ operator on the $w$? or maybe it is $\langle pi, w\rangle$, so $\pi$ is a "row"-vector. Ok, got it.

Comment: But this system need not always have a solution...or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, apparently it should,  still unclear why for me, but I'm not very strong in linear algebra. And I already deduced that $C=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{i+1}=\frac{2(n+1-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j})}{n(n+1)}$.

Comment: Ok, with this special value of $C$ it seems to have a solution. For most values of $C$ it does not. A simple but tedious way to obtain the solution is to use the explicit diagonalization that we know and solve; e.g., let $P=UDU^{-1}$, then solve $(I-D)y=U^{-1}a$ in closed form. The first entry of $y$ is free because $d_{11}=1$. Here, I wrote $U^{-1}w=y$; Set the first entry of $y$ by so that the constraint $\pi^TUy=0$ is satisfied. This should work out!

Comment: @Suvrit Yes, $\pi$ is a row vector, sorry. $I-P$ has a vector $\xi^T$ in its right kernel, hence the system can have a solution only if $\xi^Ta=0$. If it does, then call $w'$ a solution; all other solutions have the form $w'+ky$, where $k$ is a scalar and $y$, with positive entries, is a vector in the (one-dimensional) right kernel of $I-P$. The normalization condition $\pi w=0$ determines $k$ uniquely, since $\pi y >0$. So the solution exists iff $\xi^T a=0$ and is unique. This argument works for every irreducible stochastic matrix $P$.

Comment: (there is nothing new or original in my previous message by the way. It is not exactly in my field but it should be standard material; if you want a reference to start, I first encountered these topics in http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2444).

Comment: Thanks for the link Federico. I'm feeling too lazy to work out a solution following my suggestion, hopefully the OP does it!